# FVWM HowTo Swallow?

Tags: x11, window-management, window-decorations, fvwm

1. How could I **swallow** things like `xclock`, `tray` and other stuff to
   `FvwmButtons`?
2. Is `FvwmButtons` the only option to swallow this type of things?
3. How to swallow `FvwmWinList` to `FvwmButtons`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a user of FvwmButtons -- I like a pretty minimal desktop with everything in pop-up menus -- but I can quote the man page ;)

> **Swallow** *[(flags)] hangon command*
>
> Causes FvwmButtons to execute
>   *command*, and when a window with a name, class or resource matching
>   *hangon* appears, it is captured and swallowed into this button. The
>   *hangon* string may contain wildcard characters ('*') that match any
>   substring [...] If no matching window is found, the "Exec"
>   command creates one.

So I would assume that, e.g.,

```
Swallow xterm 'Exec xterm &'
```

Will do exactly that.  It's a little ambiguous whether the *command* is always run, or just when *hangon* doesn't match any existing windows, but experimentation should solve that.

Keep in mind that X windows "names, classes, and resources" are not always obvious -- I'd hope that the match does include what you see in the title bar, but this may not be so straightforward.  Enclosing the *hangon* string in wildcards (e.g. `Swallow *xterm*`) will probably help.